# Dovecot fails to create autoexpunge lock file for every specific mailbox

Tags: dovecot, lockfile

Set as fillows: `mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir`

Dovecot error record for every mailbox:

```
Error: autoexpunge: Couldn't create dovecot.autoexpunge.lock lock: file_create_locked(/var/vmail/<full_email>/dovecot.autoexpunge.lock) failed: safe_mkstemp(/var/vmail/<full_email>/dovecot.autoexpunge.lock) failed: No such file or directory
```

The problem is it tries to create `/var/vmail/<full_email>/dovecot.autoexpunge.lock` WITHOUT checking for existence and creating `<full_email>` dir in it.
This leads to `No such file or directory` error.

If I do `mkdir /var/vmail/<full_email>` then errors are not thrown and lockfile is created and then deleted ok.

There is NO settings regarding autoexpunge lockfiles.
CONTROL option pointing to other dir does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact problem when migrating from Dovecot's LDA to LMTP. Turns out it was a bad SQL CONCAT() query (no idea why the error wasn't produced when using the LDA?)

Anyhow, I was pointed in the right direction and checked the user's settings via `doveadm user name@domain.tld` which listed the user's home as `/var/vmail/name@domain.tld`. This was related to Dovecot's SQL lookup query in `/usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext`. My previous query was:

`user_query = SELECT CONCAT('/var/vmail/', maildir) as home, 110 AS uid, 110 AS gid, CONCAT('*:bytes=', quota) AS quota_rule FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'`

As you can see, the CONCAT() for "home" was merging both "/var/vmail" and "maildir" (which was name@domain.tld.) Simply removing the CONCAT() for "home" and specifying it using Dovecot's variables resolved the issue:

`user_query = SELECT '/var/vmail/%d/%n' as home, 110 AS uid, 110 AS gid, CONCAT('*:bytes=', quota) AS quota_rule FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'`

Hope this helps!